# Excel - lookup a range of data to match characters in string

Tags: excel, search, lookup

I googled like crazy before I came here.

I have 2 columns of information (I have to use alternate data for privacy). See below.

I would like in a 3rd column to look thru the list (or the range) of the first column and return the matching word. For example, I need the 3rd column for the first sentence (There is a cup on the counter) to say "CUP".

I've tried all sorts of combinations of functions and I can't quite get it right.

```
1st column    2nd column                       3rd column
Desk          There is a cup on the counter    **Result should be: Cup**
Chair         You need to plug the cord in
Cup           The desk is red
Cord          I have a large computer
Computer      I put the chair over there
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming row 1 is a header row, put this formula in cell C2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(B2,"*"&$A$2:$A$6&"*"),),0)),"")
```